# AngularJS evaluate a string in a function to call property on json list

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I wish I could give this a more descriptive title, but I don't really know the name of what I am trying to do. I have a JSON list in angular that looks like this:

```
$scope.users =
    {
        // list name and the "title" must be the same
        Guest:
        {
            title: 'Guest',
            list:
            [
                { id: "0", name: "Stephen" },
                { id: "1", name: "Mitch"},
                { id: "2", name: "Nate"},
                { id: "3", name: "Rob" },
                { id: "4", name: "Capt. Jack"},
                { id: "5", name: "Herman" }
            ]

        },
        Admin:
        {
            title: 'Admin',
            list:
            []
        }
    };
```

And I need to dynamically evaluate a string (either "Guest" or "Admin" or any other user-group that hasn't been created) in order to move a user from one user-group to another.

The function I am working with looks like:

```
$scope.moveUser = function(fromId, toId, index) {
        scope.users.toId.list.push(scope.users.fromId.list[index]);
        scope.users.fromId.list.splice(index, 1);
};
```

with "fromId" and "toId" being strings that evaluate to the name of a user-group ("Admin" or "Guest"). Right now, the function is trying to find a JSON field called "toId" and errors when it can't find any. How would I evaluate the string first so that if the toId == "Guest" and the fromId == "Admin", my function becomes:

```
scope.users.Guest.list.push(scope.users.Admin.list[index]);
scope.users.Admin.list.splice(index, 1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your **$scope.moveUser** function to

```
$scope.moveUser = function(fromId, toId, index) {
    $scope.users[toId].list.push($scope.users[fromId].list[index]);
    $scope.users[fromId].list.splice(index, 1);}
```

it is really work

Comment: Yes! That works! Do you know the name of that kind of run-time evaluation? Also, is it particular to angular or is it a vanilla javascript thing?

Comment: no it is not particular to angularjs it is a amazing javascript thing and excuse me :( i don't know the name of this kind of evaluation . excuse me again for my bad writing english

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly:

```
$scope.moveUser = function(fromId, toId, index) {
        if (users.hasOwnProperty(fromId) && users.hasOwnProperty(toId)) {
          scope.users.toId.list.push(scope.users.fromId.list[index]);
          scope.users.fromId.list.splice(index, 1);
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
};
```

Comment: This does the same thing. It still tries to find a "toId" field in the JSON rather than finding scope.users.Admin.list...

The error is Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'list' of undefined